# Conditional formatting based on the values in two different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to conditionally format only empty cells in Column N that coincide with TRUE values in the same row of Column L.

I have managed to find a way to conditionally format using each selection individually with the following code.

1. `=L13:L339=True`
2. `=ISBLANK(N13:N339)`

Despite trying I have not been able to successfully combine the two criteria using AND logic and was wondering if that is the right way to proceed?

[image: workbook screenshot, boolean values shown for reference]

For reference, in the image above I would want cell N15 to be highlighted because the value in L15 is true and the cell in N15 is currently blank.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to **highlight** **cells** where

• `L13:L339=TRUE`

• `N13:N339=""`

[image]

---

Please follow the steps to accomplish this task,

• First select the range from `N13:N339`

• From **Home** Tab => Under **Styles Group** ==> Click **Conditional Formatting**,

• Click **New** => **New Formatting Rule** Dialog opens,

• Click on the **Last rule** ==> **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**

• In the **Edit the rule description** paste the below formula,

```
=(L13=TRUE)*(N13="")
```

• Click on **Format** ==> Choose your preferred formatting( **Fill Color**, **Font Color** etc.)

• Press **Ok Twice**. And it's Done.

---

**Note:** In the example screenshot I have used range from `N13:N16`, also to hide the `TRUE` & `FALSE`'s, I have used a custom formatting, to hide them, select the range press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> ==> **Format** Dialog ==> **Number** Tab ==> **Custom** ==> Remove anything that shows below type and write.

```
;;;
```

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked perfectly. Just for some clarification, what does using the custom type ";;;" do exactly? How would this be different to making the text white so it appears 'invisible' which is my current process.

Comment: Using that custom formatting it hides the `TRUE`'s & `FALSE` thus making it look good, as in anyways whenever a checkbox is marked it is True and when not marked it is false. It hides but doesn't delete note that, custom formatting is facade